# baseUrl and paths resolution using Webpack 2 and awesome-typescript-loader

Tags: typescript, webpack, tsconfig, webpack-2

I want to setup my project so where ever I use the line below:

```
import { BlahBlahService } from '@blahblah/core/BlahBlahService';
```

it is resolved to:

> ./dist/blahblah/core/BlahBlahService

I already have read through online resources and applied the instructed settings (which I also include below). This is working in Visual Studio Code; i.e. It is not showing error to me hence it is able to correctly read my settings at tsconfig and understand it. I want to make the same thing happen to Webpack.

However I am getting the following error:

> ERROR in ./xxxxxxxxxxx.ts
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@blahblah/core/BlahBlahService' in 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

I have the following setup in my web application:

- Angular 2 Version 2.2.0
- Typescript Version 2.0.8
- Webpack Version 2.1.0-beta.26
- awesome-typescript-loader Version 2.2.4

I also have the following in my tsconfig:

```
"compilerOptions": {

    ...

    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
       "@blahblah/core": ["./dist/blahblah/core"],
       "@blahblah/core/*": ["./dist/blahblah/core/*"],
    }

    ...

 }
```

And I have the following setting in my webpack.js file:

```
plugins: [

    ...

    new TsConfigPathsPlugin(),

    ...
],
```

Comment: Try tu up version of typescript to 2.1. According to https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#path-mapping it should work without plugin.

Answer (score 4):

I'm currently working with `webpack@3.10` and `webpack-dev-server@2.9.7`.
Same issue. I found the solution [in a github issue](https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader/issues/311).

**tsconfig.js:**

```
"compilerOptions": {

    ...

    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
        "~/*": ["./src"],
    }
}
```

**webpack.config.js:**

```
var TsConfigPathsPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').TsConfigPathsPlugin;

resolve: {
    alias: {
        "~/": "./src"
    },
    plugins: [
        new TsConfigPathsPlugin()
    ]
}
```

Comment: To be clear, the `alias` does not seem to be required. The problem is that the line that adds the plugin, `new TsConfigPathsPlugin()`, needs to be under the *`resolve`* block. Not just `plugins` under the main options object but `resolve.plugins`.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. It should work but it isn't.

My workaround is adding "browser" attribute to package.json, with same aliases as in tsconfig.

**package.json**

```
{
   "name": "app",
   ...
   "browser": {
      "@blahblah/core": ["./dist/blahblah/core"],
      "@blahblah/core/*": ["./dist/blahblah/core/*"]
   },
   "scripts": { ... },
   ...
}
```

Comment: I have not tried this yet but I grant the bounty to you anyway because it was about to expire. I will try this out and will let you know if it fixed my issue. Thanks.

Comment: So did you let him know ?

Comment: if you copy "paths" from tsconfig to webpack's resolve.alias, it should work. Its not a great solution, however I believe there is a plugin for it 'TsConfigPathsPlugin'. https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader/issues/311